# Compile java class with NetBeans but error with console on Linux

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

In NetBeans 8.0.2 I've done a simple "Hello World" class that compiles and everything is fine.

```
public class OOP_HW3 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hi ");
    }
}
```

On the other hand when I navigate to this folder with console and run:

```
$ javac OOP_HW3.java // OK 
$ java OOP_HW3 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: OOP_HW3 (wrong name: oop_hw3/OOP_HW3)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
....
```

I can easily run this file with console in any other directory, but here in the NetBeans project gives me error. What am I missing ?

Comment: You have no package declaration above `public class OOP_HW3`?

Comment: I have actually - package oop_hw3;

Comment: That explains it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following commands from where you are running current command like:

```
cd ..
java oop_hw3.OOP_HW3
```

Since you are using package, you need to be on one top i.e. parent directory and then run with fully qualified package name followed by class where you define main method.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `package` definition from the top of your java file.